# Scraping Data from a Website VBA, Alike Classname

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Hi i have a Question: How can i reference to a class in from a Website but don't write the complete text from the class. Here a the classes i want to reference.

```
            <div class="nm-engine-item nm-check-list-item nm-j-configurator-item nm-j-configurator-status_11000 nm-j-configurator-item-forceselectable" data-configurator-id="8XFASG0" data-filter-criteria-fueltype="benzin" data-filter-criteria-gear="S tronic" data-filter-criteria-trimline="trimline_default" data-filter-criteria-drive="Framhjulsdrift" data-configurator-group="id_a1sb_engines" data-message="" data-mbvid="8XFASG\0-51027\2017"> </div>
            <div class="nm-engine-item nm-check-list-item nm-j-configurator-item nm-j-configurator-status_11010 nm-j-configurator-item-forceselectable" data-configurator-id="8XFBSG0" data-filter-criteria-fueltype="benzin" data-filter-criteria-gear="S tronic" data-filter-criteria-trimline="trimline_sport" data-filter-criteria-drive="Framhjulsdrift" data-configurator-group="id_a1sb_engines" data-message="" data-mbvid="8XFBSG\0-51027\2017"></div>
```

Like you can see the class is the same except for 11010 and 11000. And therefore in my code i had to write 2 For Each sectors to go throw those classes. Are there any other allternative ?
Something like:

For Each configurator_id(0) In engine_list.classname like "nm-engine-item nm-check-list-item nm-j-configurator-item nm-j-configurator-status_*"

The code Works but with if there is something like that posible it would be an improvement

```
            For Each engine_list In doc.GetElementsByClassName("clearfix nm-md-engine-selection-group")
                'wsNew.Cells(2, 1).Value = engine_list.innerText
                hubraum_o = engine_list.GetElementsByClassName("nm-el-hdl nm-el-hdl-03 nm-at-hdl-b")
                hubraum = hubraum_o.innerText
                'Debug.Print hubraum

                For Each configurator_id(0) In engine_list.GetElementsByClassName("nm-engine-item nm-check-list-item nm-j-configurator-item nm-j-configurator-status_11010 nm-j-configurator-item-forceselectable")
                    mbv(0) = configurator_id(0).getAttribute("data-configurator-id")
                    mbv_6(0) = Left(mbv(0), 6)
                    'Debug.Print mbv_6(0)
                    trimline(0) = configurator_id(0).getAttribute("data-filter-criteria-trimline")
                    'Debug.Print trimline(0)
                    preis_o(0) = configurator_id(0).GetElementsByClassName("nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04 nm-j-configurator-text-price")
                    preis(0) = preis_o(0).innerText
                    'Debug.Print preis(0)
                    co2_o(0) = configurator_id(0).GetElementsByClassName("nm-EngineEmission nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04")
                    co2(0) = co2_o(0).innerText
                    'Debug.Print co2(0)
                    kw_o(0) = configurator_id(0).GetElementsByClassName("nm-Power nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04")
                    kw(0) = kw_o(0).innerText
                    'Debug.Print kw(0)

                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 1).Value = mbv_6(0)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 2).Value = "Land MBV"
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 3).Value = modell & "-" & modell_links
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 4).Value = trimline(0)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 5).Value = kw(0)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 6).Value = hubraum
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 7).Value = co2(0)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 8).Value = preis(0)

                    mbv_6(0) = Empty
                    trimline(0) = Empty
                    kw(0) = Empty
                    co2(0) = Empty
                    preis(0) = Empty

                    zc_audi = zc_audi + 1
                Next configurator_id(0)

                For Each configurator_id(1) In engine_list.GetElementsByClassName("nm-engine-item nm-check-list-item nm-j-configurator-item nm-j-configurator-status_11000 nm-j-configurator-item-forceselectable")
                    mbv(1) = configurator_id(1).getAttribute("data-configurator-id")
                    mbv_6(1) = Left(mbv(1), 6)
                    'Debug.Print mbv_6(1)
                    trimline(1) = configurator_id(1).getAttribute("data-filter-criteria-trimline")
                    'Debug.Print trimline(1)
                    preis_o(1) = configurator_id(1).GetElementsByClassName("nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04 nm-j-configurator-text-price")
                    preis(1) = preis_o(1).innerText
                    'Debug.Print preis(1)
                    co2_o(1) = configurator_id(1).GetElementsByClassName("nm-EngineEmission nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04")
                    co2(1) = co2_o(1).innerText
                    'Debug.Print co2(1)
                    kw_o(1) = configurator_id(1).GetElementsByClassName("nm-Power nm-el-pg nm-el-pg-04")
                    kw(1) = kw_o(1).innerText
                    'Debug.Print kw(1)

                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 1).Value = mbv_6(1)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 2).Value = "Land MBV"
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 3).Value = modell & "-" & modell_links
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 4).Value = trimline(1)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 5).Value = kw(1)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 6).Value = hubraum
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 7).Value = co2(1)
                    wsNew.Cells(zc_audi, 8).Value = preis(1)

                    mbv_6(1) = Empty
                    trimline(1) = Empty
                    kw(1) = Empty
                    co2(1) = Empty
                    preis(1) = Empty

                    zc_audi = zc_audi + 1

                Next configurator_id(1)
```

Thanks this is the link: 
http://www.audi.se/se/web/sv/models/a1/a1-sportback.html#page=/se/web/sv/models/a1/a1-sportback/motorer.html

Comment: Why not to use just `.GetElementsByClassName("nm-engine-item")`?

Comment: @omegastripes Thank you it worked, i should have thought about it!!!